# Zend loader intel sense enabling

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, intellisense, phpdoc

I have on many ocasions code which works with results from the client loader.
In our application we always have code like

```
  $serviceManager = new ServiceManagerComposite(new   ConfigurationComposite($configuration['service_manager']));
                $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfiguration', $configuration);
                $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
                $clientLoader = $serviceManager->get('ClientLoad');
                $clientLoader->switchClient($client_module['module_name']);
```

Now we have a slay of things which get retrived via:

```
  $WhateverTheNever = $serviceManager->get('WhateverTheNever');
```

My question is, how can i tell intell sense via

```
/**
 * 
 * @return type
 */
```

In the get() function from ZF so it can gues all the classes it can return?

The goal is to get Intel sense on `$WhateverTheNever` after it gets retrived from the service manager. Can i somhow note it like `@return classA, ClassB...`?

If it hellps, i use Netbeans 7.4 for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @return tag does allow for multiple types to be listed:  "@return classA|classB|classC".  Use the pipe as the delimiter rather than the comma.

(http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/return.html)